# Join thread while condition

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want to add a breakpoint command to this custom scripting language processed in Java. To this effect I want to implement logic like this:

```java
//frozen = AtomicBoolean
void tick() {
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::executeFunctions);
    while(!frozen.get() && !future.isDone());
}
```

I want to run executeFunctions asynchronously with the logic described above but avoiding busy-waiting.

If no breakpoint function is called, wait for future to complete.
Else, return from tick() early and don't wait for the remainder of executeFunctions to execute.

The problem I'm having is I don't know how to join until either the thread finishes OR an external predicate is met (frozen.get() returns true)

I need to check frozen while future is running because the breakpoint command will set frozen to true when it runs.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `CompletableFuture#join`, which will block the current thread until a result is available. From there, you can simply check the result directly, no loops needed. In essence, `if (!frozen.get()) { future.join(); }`

Comment: Hi Rogue! What the breakpoint command does is freeze the thread where it is when it is called, so if a breakpoint command is run join() will wait until resume is called elsewhere (this functionality already exists), which is fine. But that means I have to check frozen.get() while future is running because the breakpoint command will set the state of frozen during the execution of future.

Comment: I think a tick-based approach (and using `frozen`) might actually be harmful in this regard. In your custom scripting language, a loop could be introduced by the programmer, but otherwise should simply run start-to-finish. There's "static" breakpoints (ones set before the script is executed) and "dynamic" breakpoints (ones set while running), but in either case your interpreter will need to track the line that the breakpoint is set for, and _then_ freeze (via a `Future`) once that line is reached.